# Getting a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined'

Tags: javascript

I inherited a piece of appscript from a previous person. Though it all looks right I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
setTimestamp    @ Donetimestamp.gs:8
```

The code is:

```
const DONE_COL = 13;
const STAMP_COL = 16;

function setTimestamp(e) {
  let timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+11", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

  // extract what we need from the range of the selected cell
  let range = e.range;
  let sheet = range.getSheet();
  let row = range.getRow();
  let col = range.getColumn();
  let value = range.getValue();

  if (col === DONE_COL && value === "Yes") {
    sheet.getRange(row, STAMP_COL).setValue(timestamp);
  } 
}
```

I tried to debug myself but cannot understand why range is undefined. I made a copy of previous code but it fails. The error is happening on line 8 "let range = e.range;"

Comment: _“cannot understand why range is undefined”_ — No, read the error message again, very carefully. _What_ is undefined? Why do you think it’s `range`?

Comment: `e` is undefined ‍♂️

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the function that is calling this function? apparently, `e` is not defined.

Comment: Sorry folks. Day 2 of 'coding' here, just trying to make something that used to work, still work. I thought e would be defined by it being set in "function setTimestamp(e)"

Comment: @Tam A parameter gets assigned its value when a function is called and is taken from the corresponding argument. You don’t seem to pass any arguments when calling this function, so the value is `undefined`. How would the function know what `e` is supposed to be?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, i really appreciate the help. That hasnt solved it for me but its given me more to look up to try and figure it out

Comment: You need to define `e` when you call your function, otherwise you're telling it to do something, but it doesn't know what to do. You can learn about functions here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0):

You can console the argument e, so you will get an idea about what the key value pair of the object. The only way to get this error is the range key is not present inside e object or else e is not a object type

Comment: Which object? `undefined` isn’t an object. `e` is clearly undefined. The error message says that it fails to read a property of undefined, not that the property itself is undefined.

Comment: I'm just saying that e does not have a key of range, you misunderstood the context. He is trying to access a value by key so it would be an object type.Hence i mentioned object